# How to create a Parent/Child relationship with Django REST models?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, erd

I am new to Django REST and want to basically create a
[join table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVRlR.png).

One Page (txt doc) can have a parent and child Page. Each and every Page can be a parent and child of multiple other pages.

Both the Page Entity and PageToPage Entity have an implemented model & serializer in the backend, where the `serializers.py` look like this:

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ['pkid', 'title', 'text', 'creation_date', 'page_of_user']

class PageToPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
      parent_page = PageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
      child_page = PageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
      class Meta:
          model = PageToPage
          fields = ['pkid', 'parent_page', 'child_page']
```

and `models.py` :

```
class Page(models.Model):
    pkid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    page_of_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='pages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class PageToPage(models.Model):
    pkid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    parent_page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='parent_page', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    child_page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='child_page', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

When entering the manage.py shell and creating a PageToPage object, it just yields empty results:

```
# Create Pages
p1 = Page(title="Parent Page 1", text="Once upon a time, there was a young man...", page_of_user=u2)
p1.save()
p3 = Page(title="Child Page 1", text="Once upon a time, there was a young man...", page_of_user=u2)
p3.save()

# Create Page Relationships
ptp = PageToPage(parent_page=p1, child_page=p3)
ptp.save()

# Select all Pages
print("Created Pages:")
ser2 = PageSerializer(Page.objects.all(), many=True)
print(ser2.data)

# Select all Page to Page relationships
ser_ptp = PageToPageSerializer(PageToPage.objects.all())
print("Created Page relationships:")
print(ser_ptp.data)
```

Output:

```
>>> Created Pages:
>>> [OrderedDict([('pkid', 1), ('title', 'Test Page number 1'), ('text', 'Just some sample text'), ('creation_date', '17.06.2021'), ('page_of_user', UUID('eeec0437-75f2-44ba-935d-96fcb78e38c6'))]), ...]
>>> Created Page relationships:
>>> {}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: share your `models.py`.

Comment: @Jimmar thx for your reply! Just added the models.py and serializers.py regarding these 2 entities to my question.

Comment: Is there a reason for  you to have this PageToPage model ? why not have the child and parent in the Page model  as ManyToMany? Django will create the join table for you

Comment: add `many=True` in `PageToPageSerializer(PageToPage.objects.all())`?

Comment: @Jimmar I simply did not know that existed. As mentioned, I am really new to Django^^ but now I got it working so thank you very much!

Comment: if you found a solution, you can post it as an answer and mark it as correct answer, glad I was of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I deleted my PageToPage stuff and changed my PageModel and Serializer as suggested by @Jimmar:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    pkid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    page_of_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='pages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent_p = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='parent_page', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    child_p = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='child_page', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

Note that I added `symmetrical=False` in the ManyToManyField to make my ends meet.